# Hibernate (4.1.2) and Spring (3.1.2) – ManyToMany relationship does not store records in JoinTable

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem and need your help to overcome this issue. Hopefully, this tread may become a reference for similar issues…

In my minimized business model there are Users and Titles. Titles should be created first and can be assigned to many Users, and Users may share the same Titles. Therefore I have created two entities called User and Title with a @ManyToMany relationship and decided that Title should own this relationship. Additionally, I have a UnitTest to run this example.

**User Entity**

```
public class User {

    Long id;
    String name;
    Set<Title> titles = new HashSet<Title>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /*============ Approach1 ============*/
//  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    /*============ Approach2 ============*/
//  @ManyToMany
    /*============ Approach3 ============*/
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( name = "tb_title_user",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "title_id"))
    public Set<Title> getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }
    public void setTitles(Set<Title> titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }

}
```

**Title Entity**

```
public class Title {

    Long id;
    String description;
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /*============ Approach1 & Approach2 & Approach3 ============*/
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( name = "tb_title_user",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "title_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**UnitTest**

```
public class UserTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String now = new Date().toString();

        Title title = new Title();
        title.setDescription("TitleDescription: " + now);
        session.save(title);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("UserName: " + now);
        user.getTitles().add(title);

        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

}
```

If you look at the code above, you are going to see three different approaches. Below, is described if the data is stored correctly in the database tables:

```
             Title      User     JoinTable
Approach1    Yes        Yes      No
Approach2    Yes        Yes      Yes
Approach3    Yes        Yes      Yes
```

Here are my thoughts regarding each approach:

**Approach1**

According with Hibernate documentation ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#d5e5537 ) I should follow Approach1. Specially, because the documentation explicitly mentions:

> “As seen previously, the other side don't have to (must not) describe
>   the physical mapping: a simple mappedBy argument containing the owner
>   side property name bind the two.”

If I understood right, I don’t have to (must not) add a @JoinTable in the User entity.

**Approach2**

It works, but it ignores my @JoinTable definition and creates its own table called: `tb_user_tb_title`. It smells fishy to me.

**Approach3**

It works, but the documentation says to do not use it. So, it seems to me that I may regret using this approach in an enterprise product.

Comment: I feel that you have miss-relation, according to your description above [Titles should be created first and can be assigned to many Users, and Users may share the same Titles], it should be oneToMany?!!

Comment: Hi Ahmed, it is really a ManyToMany relationship "and Users may share the same Titles". Additionally, in this example I do not require any cascading. I would say that "Titles should be created first" is relevant to my business workflow, and can be considered a business rule. Therefore, I do see any definition gap. Thanks for asking.

Comment: What's the question? As you've discovered, the documentation says you MUST used mappedBy, and MUST NOT specify a mapping on the inverse side.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, the question is: What is the right approach if I want specify my JoinTable? I am expecting to see a different approach (Approach4). If I use Approach2, Hibernate creates a JoinTable which I can not control... Let me know if it still not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only correct way is the first one:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
public Set<Title> getTitles() {
    return titles;
}

...

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "tb_title_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "title_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

The inverse side uses the `mappedBy` attribute to say: "I'm the inverse side. Go see the `users` attribute in the target entity to see how this association is mapped."

What you're doing wrong is that you only modify the inverse side in your test. JPA/Hibernate only considers the owner side to know if an association exists. So instead of doing

```
user.getTitles().add(title);
```

you should do

```
title.getUsers().add(user);
```

or even better, do both, to make sure the object graph is coherent.

I really hope that this tread becomes a reference for similar issues, but I doubt it, because I have already answered this question a gazillion times, and it keeps coming again and again, although it's clearly explained in the documentation:

> If the association is bidirectional, one side has to be the owner and one side has to be the inverse end (ie. it will be ignored when updating the relationship values in the association table):
>
> [ follows an example with the appropriate annotations on each side of a bidirectional many-to-namy association ]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much JB Nizet for your detailed explanation. It worked very well and in this example, and in my real case scenario (I was using this example just to reproduce the issue in a minimized scenario). Hopefully, I can also help the others if this issue comes up again.
Cheers.

Comment: It wasn't working for me either, until I put the cascade in the users: `@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`